# Spambot on Ubuntu Server running Nginx and PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, server

My VPS is infected with a spambot. I receive emails from the VPS host informing me spam emails are being sent and it locked down port 25.

I'm running Ubuntu (21.10) & Nginx (1.18.0) web server.

I've re-enabled port 25 to try to get to the bottom of where the spambot is by monitoring the post-fix mail queue and examining the headers.

What I am looking for is the originating script sending these emails...

postqueue -p

-- This gives me a breakdown of all the emails sent by the server in the mailqueue.

[Mail Queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXtW0.jpg)

postcat -q CA4784615B 37C

[Email Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Ehy.jpg)

--- This command when applied to the message ID of a sample spam email gives me attached information.

I think I need to find the originating PHP script, so I have enabled logging that in the header of emails.

[Enabled PHP Originating Script Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxMcC.jpg)

When I look at the header of emails after enabling X-PHP-Originating-Script logging, it still doesn't show what it sending the emails or location.

Can anyone help? This is really annoying my customers as no emails are being sent by the server and all contact forms are down.

Thanks,

Adam

**EDIT** Found a potential solution:**

I installed Sophos v9 antivirus for Linux:

https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/downloads/endpoint-client

Enabled on-demand scanning and ran a quick scan:

It found this:

[Sophos Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXGCv.jpg)

Minus the domain names in question, it found PHP/WebShell-O -- an exploit that can be used for botnets.

Since wiping all the files in question, unblocking port 25 at the network layer & watching the mail queue, I don't see any spam!

Will keep monitoring, but this might be the end of it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you infected (software from an unknown source is running on your machine) or do you run an open relay (anybody from outside can reach your server via port 25 and load off tons of spam to be sent)?

If you are infected by something, the only real proper solution is, to re-setup the whole machine from scratch. (This includes the operating system.)

Don't forget to take a backup first, so you can access individual data and configuration files, but get all executable stuff installed from a clean source.

This is a very harsh solution and a deep cut, but if you were infected, you don't know what else is going on on your computer. There could be a backdoor installed that re-infects everything within a minute, if you just try to "clean up quickly".

You also have to scan your system for any known vulnerabilities, because if you simply set up the same system again, the infection could happen again before you even finished installation.

If you "just" run an open relay server, the server re-setup is not necessary. In that case you have to limit access to your SMTP server for just localhost (by configuring postfix to just listen to localhost interface) or by some limited source IP addresses (with a firewall configuration) and even better try to add some form of authentication for the SMTP server.

In general nowadays running a full featured SMTP server on your own machine is a critical mission - potential for abuse is really high. I would recommend that you just have a tiny "forwarder" for your local host or have the applications use another SMTP server run by a professional provider.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice. 

This isn't my own machine, it is a commercial VPS hosted in a datacentre. 

Emails are locked down at port 25.

It is not an option at the moment to start from scratch. Surely someone knows something about how to trace the script sending the emails?

Comment: What I wanted to point out: did you think about the possibility that it is not a script on the server sending the spam, but somebody from outside?

Comment: It could be - but how would I sniff that out? Should I run an open relay server? FYI the server just hosts a bunch of WordPress and Magento websites, where contact forms are the only thing we need to send emails for.

Comment: You _should_ not run an open relay server, but your usage of postfix commands indicated the possibility to me that you are doing it.
Also your usage of `sudo` lets me think that the machine it might not be your own hardware but you have root access and therefore are responsible for everything that's running on the machine?

Comment: ^^ Correct. So what do you recommend re finding out how the emails are being sent (either locally or remotely?)

Comment: Think about the possibility that the contact forms could be abused, if they allow somehow to set the receivers address (the "to" or "cc" or "bcc" fields for an email). You can try to build in logging into the scripts for the contact forms, so you can then cross check the log of the outgoing emails with the logs of the scripts.
If you do that, please also be sure to test that logging.